# Angular ng build brakes the lazy loading

Tags: angular, build, lazy-loading

I have an app with the lazy loading configure and with ng serve is working but when i do ng build then stop working and im not receiving any error.

Is there any process im missing ? i even read the angular official docs and does not seem to be missing anything.

I install the app with angular CLI 'ng new project-x'. i have the minimum libraries.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "single-boilerplate",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/store": "^6.5.7",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/es6-shim": "^0.31.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.90",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

This is my main router :

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', loadChildren: './components/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', loadChildren: './components/auth/auth.module#AuthModule' }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '404'
  }
];
```

I dont now what is the problem. Have this happend to anyone of you?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Try deleting your `package.lock.json` (or `yarn.lock.json`) file, delete your `node_modules` folder, remove any reference to webpack in your `package.json` file (you don't appear to have one, but you can't have two versions of webpack installed just the one provided via the CLI), and then run `npm install`.

A way to check if two version of webpack are installed is by running `npm ls webpack`, but again you don't appear to have one unless it wasn't saved to your `package.json`.

I found this solution on [Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6417#issuecomment-334859000), and it worked for me, and apparently a couple other posters.

**Solution 2**

It also appears that some people simply updated to a newer version of 4.x if the above doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm going to try.

Comment: The app loads the same way but when i tried to access a url like /login then i get 404 not found. @mtpultz

Comment: What does your routing look like for your auth module?

Comment: Like this:

export const AuthRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
      { path: 'forgot', component: ForgotComponent },
      { path: 'create', component: CreatePasswordComponent },
      { path: '401', component: Error401Component },
      { path: '403', component: Error403Component },
      { path: '404', component: Error404Component },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '404'
      }
    ]
  }
];

Comment: what happens if you comment out your dashboard routes? or provide a path to your routes like `auth` in your `AppModule` where your setting up the lazy loading so the full path would be `/auth/login`

Comment: where do i do that ? in the main router or in the auth router ?

Comment: In the main route you can try these 2 things to see if you can get routing working, and also display route issues in the console using the 3rd - https://pastebin.com/4t1cGTCs.  Outside of this I think you'll need to make a https://jsfiddle.net/ of your application or post your code somewhere.

Comment: so far i tried the first solution and funny thing happend: im being redirected to the 404 component. but i cant access it via URL. im going to try the second soluction.

Comment: the problem seems to be that componentes of lazy load modules cannot be access via url

Comment: You'll need to post your code somewhere or make a jsfiddle so I can try and debug the issue, otherwise there's not enough information as far as I can see to help solve the problem :(